ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The requested identity has not been assigned to this resource
I'm trying to access SQL Database using Managed Identity from AKS cluster. I Configured and deployed my python application on Azure Kubernetes Cluster. The problem is configuring my resource to have a managed identity” in Azure. We followed and configured managed identity from Microsoft spec doc and but it didn't work.
Error:

ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The requested identity has not been assigned to this resource.

Steps Followed:

Assigned role “SQL DB Contributor” and enabled Managed Identity to AKS Cluster.

from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential
import pyodbc, struct
import pandas as pd

def get_conn():
    
    connection_string = "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:XXXXXX.database.windows.net,1433;Database=XXXXX;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30"
    
    credential = ManagedIdentityCredential(client_id="XXXXXX") # Client id of Managed Identity
    token_bytes = credential.get_token("https://database.windows.net/.default").token.encode("UTF-16-LE")
    
    token_struct = struct.pack(f'<I{len(token_bytes)}s', len(token_bytes), token_bytes)
    
    SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN = 1256  # This connection option is defined by microsoft in msodbcsql.h
    conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, attrs_before={SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN: token_struct})
    
    return conn

def get_all():
    
    with get_conn() as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table_data")
        
        data = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
        print(data.head())
        
    return

Also created a User in SQL,
CREATE USER [Msi_name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [Msi_name];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [Msi_name];
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [Msi_name];
GO

Any advise would be appreciated and helpful. Thanks

The AKS Cluster can't be linked directly with a Managed Identity, as you would do with another resource like a Virtual Machine or an Azure Function.
Within your AKS Cluster, so inside your Kubelet, you get an identity platform which is separated than your Microsoft Entra ID Identity Platform (or at least not directly connected so to say).
It does not mean you can't use your Managed Identity, but you need a step first.
You must accomplish a Token Exchange between your AKS Cluster User Identity and Microsoft Entra ID. Then with the token of Entra ID, you can perform operations on Azure Control Plane.

It can be done via Workload Identity, which is practical. That means your Identity Provider of the AKS Cluster can be trusted by Entra ID to fetch tokens.
Microsoft does provide a nice tutorial for it. Since you have already your AKS Cluster up and running and a Managed Identity, you need only to:

Update Your AKS Cluster
Retrieve the OIDC issuer URL
Create a variable for the managed identity's client ID
Create a Kubernetes Service Account
Create the federated identity credential
Eventually redeploy

You can follow all steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/workload-identity-deploy-cluster#update-an-existing-aks-cluster

Thank you very much for an detailed explanation. It's really helpful. As you advised, will try those steps and redeploy my application and check. Thank you

As you advised, I have followed the Microsoft Tutorial and performed,
Updated AKS Cluster,
Retrieved the OIDC issuer URL,
Created a Kubernetes Service Account and the federated identity credential,
And deployed my application yaml with adding workload identity labels and service account. But still the issue is same. Did I miss anything?

On pod, trying to access like, from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential, scope = "https://database.windows.net/.default" , credential = ManagedIdentityCredential(client_id="Msi_client_id"), access_token = credential.get_token(scope)

You should use WorkloadIdentityCredential of the azure.identity Python Module to fetch your Entra Token
Example:
from azure.identity.aio import WorkloadIdentityCredential
credential = WorkloadIdentityCredential(
tenant_id="<tenant_id>",
client_id="<client_id>",
token_file_path="<token_file_path>",
)
Parameters can be omitted if the following environment variables are set:
- AZURE_TENANT_ID
- AZURE_CLIENT_ID
- AZURE_FEDERATED_TOKEN_FILE
credential = WorkloadIdentityCredential()

Thank you very much. I just looked at Workload Identity. Could you please advise how to get # token_file_path - #AZURE_FEDERATED_TOKEN_FILE. I can't find out it. Thanks
